# unittest colored output

Tags: python, unit-testing

I use `unittest` (actually `unittest2`) for Python testing, together with [Python Mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/index.html) for mocking objects and [nose](http://code.google.com/p/python-nose/) to run all tests in a single pass.

I miss being able to tell what is working and what's wrong at a glance from the green/red bars. Is there a way to get colored output from unittest?

*(Changing test suite at this point is not an option, and I actually like unittest)*

Comment: what did you use before that had the green/red bars?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In python 2.x you could try [pyrg](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyrg). Does not work in Python 3 though.

Comment: This is definitely the easiest solution.

Comment: I found the latest version (0.2.6), if run in command line mode, only waits 1ms for data on stdin - if it doesnt receive any then it falls over with a usage message. It's easy enough to change the poll timeout to a more-reasonable 1000ms

Answer (score 31):

Using a method very similar to [robert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5205341/400691), I have (today!) released a package that enables colour output in `unittest` test results. I have called it [`colour-runner`](https://github.com/meshy/colour-runner/).

To install it, run:

```
pip install colour-runner
```

Then, where you were using `unittest.TextTestRunner`, use `colour_runner.runner.ColourTextTestRunner` instead.

See [how it looks with `verbosity=1`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxZ04.png)...and [`verbosity=2`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rP64U.png)

Comment: What platforms does this work on?  I only ask because colors in terminals on Windows is very different from colors in terminals on Linux and OS X.

Comment: That's a good question. I have tested it on linux and OS X, but I don't have a Windows machine to test it on. I use two libraries to do the output. The [blessings](https://github.com/erikrose/blessings/) library claims it "should work when used in concert with [colorama](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama)" on windows, so it may need that extra package. I can't find any mention of whether [pygments](http://pygments.org/) supports windows, but I suspect that if it doesn't, colorama may resolve the issue.

I would be very interested to know how this works on windows.

Comment: Can I please have an explanation of the downvote so that I can make improvements? The downvote on its own doesn't very well lend itself to constructive action.

Comment: Is it possible to use this with nosetests, along the lines of rednose?

Comment: @naught101 I'm pretty sure that this will not work with `nose`.

Comment: Just tried on Windows, but it doesn't work since it needs the curses library.

Comment: What if my unittest ends with: if __name__ == '__main__': 
    unittest.main(verbosity=2). How to modify this to imply color please?

Comment: Does not work! any hits? def suite():
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    suite.addTest(WidgetTestCase('Test_Network2'))
    return suite


if __name__ == '__main__': 
    runner = colour_runner.runner.ColourTextTestRunner()
    runner.run(suite())

Answer (score 21):

I'm having good success with nosetests and [rednose](http://gfxmonk.net/dist/0install/rednose.xml). It's still maintained at the time of writing this.

Comment: easy_install failed for me, but pip worked fine: `sudo pip install rednose`

Comment: This works for me, `nosetests --verbosity=2 --rednose ./`, I'm using Python 3.6.8 and Nose 1.3.7. Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

Make a class that inherits from `unittest.TestResult` (say, `MyResults`) and implements a bunch of methods.  Then make a class that inherits from `unittest.TextTestRunner` (say, `MyRunner`) and override `_makeResult()` to return an instance of `MyResults`.

Then, construct a test suite (which you've probably already got working), and call `MyRunner().run(suite)`.

You can put whatever behavior you like, including colors, into `MyResults`.

Answer (score 9):

If you are running pytest this way:

```
python -m unittest test_my.py
```

Change it to:

```
pytest test_my.py
```

And you get colors for free

Answer (score 9):

[pytest](https://docs.pytest.org) can do this with no changes needed for unit tests.

[image]

Now install pytest.

```
pip install --user pytest
```

And run the tests to see the color!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you could change just the line of your test imports, you could use [`redgreenunittest`](https://github.com/stevematney/redgreenunittests). It's a clone I made of `unittest`, but it has colorized output.

If you want to use it without updating any of the meat of your code, you can just use it like so:

```
import redgreenunittest as unittest
```

It's not a clone of unittest2, so it wouldn't work out-of-the-box with Andrea's code, but its source is right there, so a `unittest2` fork of `redgreenunittest` wouldn't be out of the question.

Also, any "you're doing it wrong" comments are welcome, so long as they contain some reasoning. I'd love to do it right instead.

Answer (score 2):

I've also found another colouring plugin for nose: YANC at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yanc

Works for me with Python 3.5 and nose 1.3.7 (I couldn't get any of the other options for nose listed above to work)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer ^^ The color is lovely and best among other nose plugins

Answer (score 1):

Try [rudolf](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/rudolf/) plugin for nosetests.

Comment: No python 3 version :/