# Colorizing the output of Django tests

Tags: django

Is there a way to colorize the Django test output? 
Basically a Red/Green factor for a pass or failing results?

I am on Mac OS X using `Terminal.app`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're already using Fabric for deployment, you can use this snippet from [@codeinthehole's blog post](http://codeinthehole.com/writing/coloured-output-while-doing-tdd-with-django-and-fabric/):

```
from fabric.colors import _wrap_with

green_bg = _wrap_with('42')
red_bg = _wrap_with('41')

# Set the list of apps to test
env.test_apps = "app1 app2"

def test():
    with settings(warn_only=True):
        result = local('./manage.py test %(test_apps)s --settings=settings_test -v 2 --failfast' % env, capture=False)
    if result.failed:
        print red_bg("Some tests failed")
    else:
        print green_bg("All tests passed - have a banana!")
```

It doesn't colorise the individual test outputs, but it does give you immediate red / green satisfaction...

Answer (score 21):

[redgreenunittests](https://github.com/stevematney/redgreenunittests) is the most simple solution and it works great with python 3.x

Install it

`pip install redgreenunittest`

add the next line into *settings.py*

`TEST_RUNNER = "redgreenunittest.django.runner.RedGreenDiscoverRunner"`

and don't forget to enjoy :)

`./manage test`

Comment: Actually the package is redgreenunittest (even though the git repo has an "s"), so you'll want to run `pip install redgreenunittest`.

Answer (score 6):

I found [`pyrg`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyrg) to work quite well:

```
pyrg manage.py test
```

The required command can be installed with pip:

```
pip install pyrg
```

Comment: This didnt work for me on python3x. on OSX..pip install pyrg
Collecting pyrg
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5c/e0/ed29cec7b1ffae0ca97f0f560b8bf2265d42ead6047adcb759a1b0af6870/pyrg-0.2.6.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/0w/9y11s6qj6tvg2q3rzvgn7ytr0000gn/T/pip-install-armngvjd/pyrg/setup.py", line 7, in <module>
        import pyrg
      File "pyrg/pyrg.py", line 226                                          ^

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question, but [django-rainbowtests](https://github.com/bradmontgomery/django-rainbowtests) aims to do this. Failures and Errors are Red, Success is green, and it highlights your project's code in larger stack traces.

Answer (score 3):

If you're not using Fabric, you might like [`redgreenunittest`](https://github.com/stevematney/redgreenunittests). Basically, you just put it in the appropriate place in your project (probably in your virtual environment), and then reference it as your `TEST_RUNNER` in your settings like this:

```
TEST_RUNNER="redgreenunittest.django.simple.RedGreenTestSuiteRunner"
```

If you're only using Django's test helper code (mostly django.test.TestCase), then that should do it. otherwise you may need to reference `redgreenunittest` directly like so:

```
import redgreenunittest as unittest
```

Then you just run your tests. And they'll have colors. Like magic.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Print in terminal with colors using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors-using-python). You should be able to modify or roll out your own colorization from there.

Comment: There's also a package that does this quite easily called colorama (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama)

Answer (score 1):

I found a possible solution, called [pyrg](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyrg), in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5203633/599991).
Unfortunately, didn't work as expected for me.