# python unittest: how to get colored tracebacks like in IPython

Tags: python, exception, ipython, python-unittest, backtrace

In IPython (see [1](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/interactive/reference.html#verbose-and-colored-exception-traceback-printouts)) exception traceback printouts are much easier to understand due to human-friendly coloring and spacing.

However if I run a script containing unittests (using the unittest module of the standard library) I get the normal monochrome traceback printouts like in the standard python shell.

Q: How to combine the traceback formatting of IPython with the output of unittest module?

Comment: I flagged as duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203633/unittest-colored-output but the answer there might not be the best anymore as this is 3 years old, and we have Python 3 now, etc.

Comment: While it is not exactly what I looked for, the answer of David (http://stackoverflow.com/a/11313556/333403) serves my needs.

Comment: However, the problem of rednose (which David suggested, see my comment above) is that it does not work together with the IPython embeded shell (from IPython import embed; ... embed() ...) which I use extensively during debugging.